# Graphql timeout error and how to handle it

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I am using GatsbyJS and GraphQL. The problem I am facing is there are too many results so it is timing out and breaking the project 50% of the time. Making development a slow and annoying hit or miss process. Right now I am limiting the page to one result doing something like this:

```
{articles.data[0].title}
```

Is there a way to limit the number of results returned by GraphQL in or before my query? For example can I just look for the first ten results and load only those?'

Example Query (I am only querying a few items):

```
export const GatsbyQuery = graphql`
  {
    articleHub {
      articles {
        data {
          title
          subtitle
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `limit` to get only a certain amount of data: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/graphql-reference/#limit